# Spark UnaryTransformer implementation fails with scala.MatchError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm implementing an UnaryTransformer in Spark 1.6.2. with this interface:

```
class myUT(override val uid: String) extends UnaryTransformer[Seq[String], Seq[String], myUT] {
...
override protected def createTransformFunc: Seq[String] => Seq[String] = {
   _ => _.map(x => x + "s")
}
```

This compiles well but at runtime returns me an error:

```
17/07/21 22:29:33 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, myhost.com.au): scala.MatchError: ArrayBuffer(<contents of my array>) (of class scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
```

The next thing I tried was replace

```
_ => _.map(x => x + "s")
```

with

```
_ => _
```

So, theoretically it should mean no change of data at all! But the error I've got was:

```
17/07/21 22:11:59 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, myhost.com.au): scala.MatchError: WrappedArray(<contains of my array>) (of class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
```

So it looks like the type of outgoing data gets changes anyway. How do I avoid this?

Update: The next thing I tried adding .toArray to the map. The error is now this:

```
[error] /sparkprj/src/main/scala/sp_txt.scala:43: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [B >: String]Array[B]
[error]  required: Seq[String]
[error]                                           ).toArray
```

It may add some detail, but doesn't add much to my understanding. After reviewing a few examples of mllib UnaryTransformer I tend to believe it's a bug in Catalyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in definition of class myUT was incorrect:

```
override protected def outputDataType: DataType = new ArrayType(StringType, true)
```

As I copied this class definition from a String->String transformer, I had DataType defined as just StringType. My bad.